# Java falling matrix code (like the movie, continued)

Tags: java

ok, so yesterday i posted a question in regards to creating a java jframe that simulates the matrix rain from the movies which i want to be just like this php example

http://mgccl.com/2007/03/30/simple-version-matrix-like-animated-dropping-character-effect-in-php

but i would like some help with two things,

1st have more than one column falling at a time and
2nd having the characters trailing behind each other

this is my code so far

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainFrame extends JFrame { 

private static final int FONT_SIZE = 20;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_REPEATS = 5;
private static final String TEXT = new String("0123456789/*-+/<>?;:[]~!@#$%^&*()+=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
private static JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
private static Random random = new Random();
private static JLabel label[] = new JLabel[NUMBER_OF_REPEATS];

public MainFrame() {        
    this.add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public void scroll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_REPEATS; i++) {
        int character_initial = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());
        int random_x = random.nextInt(panel.getWidth() / FONT_SIZE) - 1;
        int colour = 255;
        label[i] = new JLabel(""+TEXT.charAt(character_initial));
        panel.add(label[i]);
        label[i].setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
        label[i].setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));

        //change the text of the labels and their position
        for (int j = 0; j < (panel.getHeight() / FONT_SIZE)*2; j++) {
            int character = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());
            label[i].setBounds(random_x*FONT_SIZE, j*(FONT_SIZE / 2), FONT_SIZE, FONT_SIZE);
            label[i].setText(""+TEXT.charAt(character));

            //if foreground colour < 255 catch exception
            try {
                //when text reaches a certain colour remove it
                label[i].setForeground(new Color(0, 255-(j*5), 0));
                colour = 255-(j*5);
                if (colour <= 80) {
                    panel.remove(label[i]);
                    repaint();
                    colour = 255;
                    j = (panel.getHeight() / FONT_SIZE)*2;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            //pause between each character
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        //create an infinite loop
        if (i == NUMBER_OF_REPEATS - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Matrix Code Emulator by Ricco");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.scroll();
}
}
```

Comment: .. Dear....Where is your questions.. ? I didnt get wt u want ..?

Comment: you know the "matrix rain" from the movies, that is what i am tring to re-create, but if you run the code i wrote so far, only one character drops at a time instead of lots, and they don't have the trailing behind effect before disappearing. but i'm not sure how to do that, thats what i need some help with.

Comment: BTW: The characters in matrix are backwards Japanese hirigana and katakana.

Comment: the title should be "Java falling matrix code Reloaded"

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class matrixRain extends JFrame { 

private static final int FONT_SIZE = 20;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_REPEATS = 5;
private static final String TEXT = new String("あ     た      
ア        カ                                  サ    ザ      ジ  
ズ       ゼ       ゾ           シ    ス      セ   ソ    キ   ク   ケ   コ   イ  ウ   エ    オ   ジャ な");
private static JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
private static Random random = new Random();
private static JLabel label[] = new JLabel[NUMBER_OF_REPEATS];

public matrixRain() {        
   this.add(panel);
   panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
public void scroll() {
    //array to hold x coordinates for the labels
    int[] random_x = new int[NUMBER_OF_REPEATS];
    //create an infinite loop
    while (true) {
        //initialise all the labels to random characters
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_REPEATS; i++) {
          int character_initial = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());
          random_x[i] = random.nextInt(panel.getWidth() / FONT_SIZE) - 1;
          label[i] = new JLabel("" + TEXT.charAt(character_initial));
          panel.add(label[i]);
          label[i].setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
        label[i].setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
     }
    // change the text of the labels and their position
    for (int j = 0; j < (panel.getHeight() / FONT_SIZE) * 2; j++) {
        int character = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());
        //move each character
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_REPEATS; i++) {
            label[i].setBounds(random_x[i] * FONT_SIZE, j * (FONT_SIZE / 2), FONT_SIZE, FONT_SIZE);
            label[i].setText("" + TEXT.charAt(character));
            label[i].setForeground(new Color(0, 255 - (j * 5), 0));     
            for (int k = 0; k < NUMBER_OF_REPEATS; k++) {
                int character_initial = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());
                random_x[k] = random.nextInt(panel.getWidth() / FONT_SIZE) - 1;
                label[k] = new JLabel("" + TEXT.charAt(character_initial));
                panel.add(label[k]);
                label[k].setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
                label[k].setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
                Color colour = label[k].getForeground();
                if (colour.getGreen() <= 80) {
                    panel.remove(label[k]);
                    k = (panel.getHeight() / FONT_SIZE) * 2;
                }
            }
        }
        // pause between each character
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
     }
  }
}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      matrixRain frame = new matrixRain();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(600, 400);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setTitle("Matrix Code Emulator by Ricco");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
      frame.scroll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JPanel{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         JFrame jf = new JFrame("Matrix raining code - by Ran Galili");
         jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         jf.setSize(700,700);
         jf.setResizable(false);
         jf.add(new Drawing());
         jf.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

Drawing.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Drawing extends JPanel{

    int FONTSIZE = 32, SCREENSIZE = 700;
    thread1[] thArr = new thread1[SCREENSIZE/FONTSIZE];
    Drawing(){
        for (int i = 0; i < thArr.length; i++) {
            thArr[i] = new thread1(i*FONTSIZE);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREENSIZE, SCREENSIZE);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, FONTSIZE);
        g2.setFont(font);
        for (int i = 0; i < thArr.length; i++) {
            if(thArr[i].y > 700){
                thArr[i] = new thread1(i*FONTSIZE);
            }
            drawThread(g2,thArr[i]);
        }

        try{Thread.sleep(30);}catch(Exception ex){}

        repaint();
    }
    public void drawThread(Graphics2D g2, thread1 th){
        int fontsize = g2.getFont().getSize();
        for (int i = 0; i < th.len; i++) {
            if(th.randInt(0, th.len) == i)
                th.chArr[i][0] = th.randChar();
            if(i == th.len-1)
                g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            else
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.drawChars(th.chArr[i] ,0 ,1 ,th.x , th.y + (i*fontsize));
        }
        th.y+=th.vel;
    }

    public class thread1{
        int vel, len, x, y, yBottom;
        char[][] chArr;

        thread1(int x){

            this.x = x;
            len = randInt(5,30);
            chArr = new char[len][1];
            chArr = populateArrWithChars(chArr);
            vel = randInt(1,5);
            this.y = (-1)*len*FONTSIZE;
        }
        public char[][] populateArrWithChars(char[][] arr){
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i][0] = randChar();
            }
            return arr;
        }
        public char randChar(){
            final String alphabet = "0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
            final int N = alphabet.length();
            Random r = new Random();
            return alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
        }
        public int randInt(int min, int max) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            return randomNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should spawn an own thread for every column drop animation (of course you need to take care to use invokeLater in order to synch with the EDT). Just start these threads in random intervals (but be careful that you don't have two active threads for one column)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you weren't seeing all characters on screen at once was because you were creating one character at a time, moving it all the way down, and then creating the next character. Instead, you need to initialise all your characters first, then move then down together. I have adjusted your code to:

```
public void scroll() {

    //array to hold x coordinates for the labels
    int[] random_x = new int[NUMBER_OF_REPEATS];

    //create an infinite loop
    while (true) {

        //initialise all the labels to random characters
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_REPEATS; i++) {
            int character_initial = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());
            random_x[i] = random.nextInt(panel.getWidth() / FONT_SIZE) - 1;
            label[i] = new JLabel("" + TEXT.charAt(character_initial));
            panel.add(label[i]);
            label[i].setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
            label[i].setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
        }

        // change the text of the labels and their position
        for (int j = 0; j < (panel.getHeight() / FONT_SIZE) * 2; j++) {
            int character = random.nextInt(TEXT.length());

            //move each character
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_REPEATS; i++) {
                label[i].setBounds(random_x[i] * FONT_SIZE, j * (FONT_SIZE / 2), FONT_SIZE, FONT_SIZE);
                label[i].setText("" + TEXT.charAt(character));
                label[i].setForeground(new Color(0, 255 - (j * 5), 0));
                Color colour = label[i].getForeground();
                if (colour.getGreen() <= 80) {
                    panel.remove(label[i]);
                    j = (panel.getHeight() / FONT_SIZE) * 2;
                }
            }
            // pause between each character
            try {
                Thread.sleep(75);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've imported Processing which makes life easier, lol .

```
import processing.core.*; 

public class Enter extends PApplet {

matrix[] red_pill = new matrix[300];
boolean exit = false;
boolean next = false;
int countDwn = 0;
int wait = 0;

public void setup() {
  //fullScreen(P3D);
  for (int index = 0; index < red_pill.length; index++)
  {
    red_pill[index] = new matrix();
  }
  wait = 500;
}
public void draw() {
  background(25, 25, 25);
  if (!exit) {
    startScreen();
    decision();
  } else{

  }
}
public void startScreen() {
  if (!next) {
    if (countDwn < wait) {
      for (int i = 0; i < red_pill.length; i++) {
        red_pill[i].show();
        red_pill[i].update();
        red_pill[i].tail();
      }
      countDwn++;
    } else {
      countDwn = 0;
      next = true;
    }
  }
}
public void decision() {
    if (next) {
    background(0, 0, 0);
    if (countDwn < wait) {
      for (int i = 0; i < red_pill.length; i++) {
        red_pill[i].show();
        red_pill[i].update();
        red_pill[i].tail();
      }
      countDwn++;
    } else {
      countDwn = 0;
      exit = true;
      next = false;
    }
  }
}
public class matrix {
   float x = 0;
   float y = 0;
   float s = 0;
   float speed = 1;
   char chr1 = '0';
   char chr2 = '0';
   char chr3 = '0';
   char chr4 = '0';
   char chr5 = '0';
   char chr6 = '0';
   int txtSize = 30;
   int count = 0;
   int frameR = 15;
   matrix() {
    x = random(-width, width);
    y = y + txtSize;
    s = random(2, 20);
    speed = s;
    chr1 = (char)random(33, 126);
    chr2 = (char)random(33, 126);
    chr3 = (char)random(33, 126);
    chr4 = (char)random(33, 126);
    chr5 = (char)random(33, 126);
    chr6 = (char)random(33, 126);
}
public void show() {
    fill(255,255,255,255);
    textSize(txtSize);
    text(chr1, x, y);
}
public void update() {
    
    if(y > displayHeight) {
      y = 0;
    } else {
      y = y + speed;
    }
  }
public void tail() {
    if(count >= frameR) {
      chr1 = (char)random(33, 126);
      chr2 = (char)random(33, 126);
      chr3 = (char)random(33, 126);
      chr4 = (char)random(33, 126);
      chr5 = (char)random(33, 126);
      chr6 = (char)random(33, 126);
      count = 0;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
    fill(0,255,0,150);
    text(chr2, x, y - txtSize);
    text(chr3, x, y - txtSize*2);
    fill(0,255,0,75);
    text(chr4, x, y - txtSize*3);
    text(chr5, x, y - txtSize*4);
    fill(0,255,0,25);
    text(chr6, x, y - txtSize*5);
  }
}
public void settings() {
    size(400, 600, P3D); 
  }
  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "Enter" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
      PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
      PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
  }
}
```